# How can I change the temperature unit in Lollipop's lock screen?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-4, weather, lock-screen-widgets

Today, Lollipop became available for my Samsung S4 and I upgraded. Since then, the lock screen shows the current temperature:

[image: start screen]
[image: configuration]

As you can see, it shows "61 °F". Since I am located in Continental Europe, I prefer Celsius.

How can I fix that? As you can see in the others screenshots (lock screen configuration), "Additional Information" is "On" and greyed out, and accessing the "lock screen widgets" menu item only lets me configure the personal message, nothing else.

I do use a third-party weather app ([Weather & Clock Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devexpert.weather&hl=en)), but I don't think this is related, since (a) the third-party app does not contain a *lock screen* widget and (b) the app is set to Celsius.

I've found [someone on the Internet with the same problem](http://www.androidpit.com/forum/645867/samsung-galaxy-s4-lollipop-lock-screen-temperature-unit-problem), but I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: The setting is actually behind the Clock built-in app. Open the Clock app, go to "Desk clock" tab, open the context menu, go to Settings there and select your unit. This will be the unit displayed in the built lock screen. Pretty obscure... (Would have answered the question, but it is protected so I can't...)

Comment: @GudlaugurEgilsson: Brilliant, good find! You should be able to answer the protected question, since you have more than 10 rep. Interestingly, as mentioned by beerallica, it just changes the unit displayed rather than the value (86 °F -> 86 °C... it's hot here, but it's not *that* hot). I'll see if that changes on the next temperature update.

Comment: Thought so too. Might be a bug or wrong message in stackExchange, this is transferred rep from stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in order to enable/disable the widget altogether, go to

**Settings > My Device > Lock Screen > Lock Screen Widgets > Clock or Personal Message**

and select **Clock**. This activates the following menu:

**Settings > My Device > Lock Screen > Additional Information**

That enables you to select whether to display a weather and/or pedometer widget on the lock screen. On the weather widget description I read:

*The data will be taken from the weather widget and shown while the device is connected to the network*

So, obviously, the units etc come from the original weather widget that comes with lollipop. What I did to correct the units is:

Add the weather widget to a spot on the home screen. Enable your GPS, let it find our where you are and fetch weather data. Tap on that widget, and the first item on its settings is the units.

**However:** although the temperature on the lock screen weather widget appears in C, it says it's F (eg instead of 10C it reads 10F). Probably one of those loose ends that will be taken care of in the next updates.

Hope this helps. It took me ages to find out how it's done.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot, changing the settings to "Clock" was the key. (Setting it back to "Personal Message" after disabling the weather lock screen widget works fine as well and keeps the weather lock screen widget disabled.) Interestingly, I don't find the original weather widget on my phone, but being able to disable the lock screen widget is enough for me. After all, if I want to see the current weather at my current location, I can just look out of the window...

Answer (score 1):

For me, Gudlaugur's comment (see above) contained the one missing (and obscure) piece of information needed to change the unit of the temperature from farenheit to celsius.

So for completeness and easier discovery I'll quote it here:

> The setting is actually behind the Clock built-in app. Open the Clock
>   app, go to "Desk clock" tab, open the context menu, go to Settings
>   there and select your unit. This will be the unit displayed in the
>   built lock screen. Pretty obscure... (Would have answered the
>   question, but it is protected so I can't...)